# type conversion of some elements of a vector of objects

Tags: c++, vector, type-conversion

I would like to play with a vector of objects. Let's assume I have a `Base` class and two derived classes: `Derived_A` and `Derived_B`.

```
class Base{...}; 
class Derived_A: public Base{}; 
class Derived_B: public Base{};
```

In the `main()` I create a vector of 10 objects of class `Derived_A` e.g.:

```
std::vector < Derived_A > array;
array.reserve(10);
```

Now, what I would like to do, is from the elements of this vector, to pick one (or several) and change its type to `Derived_B`. At the end, I would have a vector of some elements of class `Derived_A` and some of class `Derived_B`.

Is that possible? Or would you have a better way to do it?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? `Derived_A` and `Derived_B` should not be casted to each other.

Comment: You can't put a `Derived_B` in a vector of `Derived_A`. You should make it a vector of `Base`, then it can hold any of the derived classes.

Comment: @Barmar: No, a vector of `Base` can only hold `Base`. Perhaps you mean that a vector of `Base*` (or a smart pointer, if you want the vector to manage object lifetimes) can hold pointers to any derived class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that doesn't make any real sense. `Derived_A` and `Derived_B` are not compatible; only the `Base` part of each is.

If you have a `std::vector<Base*>` and `virtual` member functions, then you can [indirectly] store objects of either type, but don't go casting one to the other.

Incidentally, vectors are not arrays, and `std::vector::reserve` *does not create elements*. It only reserves memory space for them. You probably meant `std::vector::resize`.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was thinking about that in the car this morning. I need polymorphism and for that, I need to play with a vector of pointers to the Base class.

Answer (score 1):

You would need several things to be true, I would think:

1. It would have to be actually feasible to convert a Derived_A to a Derived_B, and for "sibling" classes that would be pretty unusual.
2. You would have to be storing using `Base` rather than one of the `Derived`s, and even then you couldn't be storing objects but pointers/references.
3. The conversion (probably) wouldn't happen in-place, so you may have to remove/reinsert.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
std::vector < Derived_A > array;

array.reserve(10);
```

does not define a vector of 10 objects. it defines a vector of 0 objects.

As for your question then  an object of type Derived_A may not be converted to an object of type Derived_b in general case. The usual approach in this case is to define a vector of pointers to the base class. For example

```
std::vector<Base *> v;
```

and add to it pointers to objects of Derived_A and Derived_B. The derived classes should inherite virtual functions of the base class. The destructor also has to be declared as virtual.

Comment: @ Lightness Races in Orbit, I am sorry, sir.

Comment: OK for the vector stuff. Of course I need to add objects to the vector with push_back. I just wanted to avoit too many details since I was concerned with the Derived classes. And I agree with you, I rather use a vectore of pointers to Base class. Thanks.